# Moving TSV files from Storage Bucket to Cloud MySql

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

I have TSV files in Storage Bucket and i want to move files into GCP MySQL. I have used the below script to export files from storage bucket to MySQL:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'gs://Bucket_name/pre.txt' INTO TABLE Prep FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'   IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

But i am getting an error

> " ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using
>   password: YES) "

I have reset the password and checked the bucket level permissions and database connections, all are set up correctly, but still getting the access denied error.

Comment: Just 3 quick questions. Are you 100% sure that you are using the right password? have you tried connecting into the Cloud SQL instance itself succesfully? and have you tried stopping and starting again (restarting) the Cloud SQL instance?

Comment: Hi, Yes i have changed the password and restarted the Instance a couple of times but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you can't read the source file directly from the bucket.

`LOAD DATA INFILE` can't be used to point to a bucket because it expects the file to be stored locally. Therefore, you need a copy of the TXT stored on the filesystem of the machine you are using to connect to the CloudSQL instance.

You need to [download the blob](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects) first using the gsutil tool:

```
gsutil cp gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME] [SAVE_TO_LOCATION]
```

And then upload the file to the instance following the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing#importing_the_csv_file)

For this you have to:

Add the service account to the bucket ACL as a writer:

```
gsutil acl ch -u [SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS]:W gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
```

Add the service account to the import file as a reader:

```
gsutil acl ch -u [SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS]:R gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[IMPORT_FILE_NAME]
```

Import the file:

```
 gcloud sql import csv [INSTANCE_NAME] gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[FILE_NAME] --database=[DATABASE_NAME] --table=[TABLE_NAME]
```

After this you can use the `LOAD DATA INFILE` making reference to the .txt file in your Cloud SQL instance instead of an external reference.

Comment: Thank you So much Chris, It is importing now, i have another issue here, That  i have TSV (tab Separated Files in my Bucket), If i run the above CSV command it is importing data in one column, can you please suggest me how to import the TSV file to MySql.

Comment: I managed to import a TSV file with the command `gcloud sql import  csv [INSTANCE_NAME] gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[FILE_NAME] --database=[DATABASE_NAME] --table=[TABLE_NAME]` but keep in mind that actually Cloud SQL only supports import from SQL and CSV files. I did a test with a TSV file with a lot of columns and it left some columns with NULL values, the I imported a file with just 3 columns and all went ok. I suggest you to transform your TSV file to a CSV either importing into a spread sheet and saving it as csv or with an online converter

Comment: there i have problem, i have TSV file with more than 4 million rows, so when i am trying to convert into CSV, it is limiting to 1 million. So currently i dont have option to convert that to CSV. So checking the all possibility options with TSV. I am getting the same issue that it is taking only 3 column and rest of them like NULL.

Comment: Ok, don't worry, have you tried using Big Query? you can use a command like `bq load --source_format=CSV --field_delimiter=tab \
  --skip_leading_rows 1 -<destination_table> <source> \ 
  <schema>` You can import your TSV in there and then export your file. I'm not aware of that kind of limitation in Big Query

Comment: Yeah, i have used the BQ to check the data but did not use much. Let me explain you my actual project : I have total four files (A,B,C,D). A has the complete data with more than 4M rows, and remaining files has the data related to A. So i have created the four tables in MySQL and wanted to transfer the RAW data first, Then i need to join tables to get my Actual Table with the Columns i needed. Each File has the PK to connect the data to other file.

Comment: i have about 40Sets of (A,B,C,D), So i need to load them all into one data base and join the tables to get my own Table. Now i got stuck at 1st step. Moreover, I am new to GCP, with limited knowledge of cloud based stuff. Any suggestion would be great to keep my all data at one place for analysis. Thank you.

Comment: Ok I understand that you don't want to manually transform 160 files. You can implement a better solution using a [python script](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#loading_csv_data_into_a_table) using the [field delimiter option](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#csv-options) as `Tab` and then use [another script](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_table_data) to export the data as actual csv. Does this solution fits your needs?

Comment: Hi Shiva Krishna, could you accept Chris32's answer, as it solved your issue, so it can help other community members more easily? Also, could you please make another post with the new unrelated question, so it is better organized and more helpful? Thanks!