# is there a way dump a TSV file from Storage Bucket to Cloud MySql in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

is there a way to dump a TSV file from Storage Bucket to Cloud MySql in GCP ?. I have large file of TSV with 4M rows.

I couldn't convert it into CSV.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, Cloud SQL [only supports CSV and SQL.](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/importing) Nonetheless, I suggest that you take a look at this solution. I used Python to be able to automate this process in case you really need it to make it more than one time. In this case I tried to reproduce your issue and I code a script that basically:

1. Downloads the TSV file from the Cloud Storage Bucket specified.
2. Converts the TSV file to a CSV file. Uploads the CSV file to the
3. Cloud Storage Bucket specified.
4. Imports the newly added CSV file to
   Cloud SQL.

You can find the code as well as the requirements for running [this script here](https://github.com/crodriguezconde/so-59031345). Furthermore, take into account that you will need to replace those values closed by claudators such as [BUCKET_NAME] before running it. Also keep in mind that this script does not delete the TSV download it as well as the CSV file, therefore you will need to delete it manually or you can modify the code in order to delete the files automatically.

Finally, if you would like to investigate further about the API used on the script section, I will attach the documentation need it [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/) & [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/cloud-client/snippets.py).

Comment: Thank you Christopher, Let me try this one, yes i have about 160 files to load into MySQL. Can you please also suggest me apart from MySql, are there any data bases that supports TSV file.?

Comment: As of right now, GCP does not have any databases that support TSV files natively. Consequently, my recommendation is to convert it first into a CSV file and then import it into Cloud SQL, as I mentioned in my previous answer. 

Furthermore, I can also see that you have another question and another user, Chris32 has also answered in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58992505/moving-tsv-files-from-storage-bucket-to-cloud-mysql).

In conclusion, I will suggest you to take a look at the script and modified to your needs in order to be able to import your TSV files into Cloud SQL.

Comment: Hi Chrisopher, I tried with the script you shared with me but it couldnt work, I meant i  am not that perfect with python scripting. But i convert the TSV to CSV with Pandas. Again got stuck with importing the CSV to  Could SQL. My csv file size is about 290Mbs and 2.9M rows. I tried to upload with console and with gsutil but i am getting an error of TIMEOUT. I am unable to load the the file into Cloudsql. Can you please let me know what would be the issue? and how can i transfer the file. I have increased the Instance capacity too but no luck. Thank you. Shiva

Comment: The size of the database table and/or the size of the .csv file should not affect the import into Cloud MySQL. It is however, necessary that the CSV file format [requirements](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing##csv-reqs) are met. I also attached you documentation about [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/#tips_for_long-running_import_and_export_processes) when running import and export processes.

Comment: Furthermore, I attached you the documentation to [import the csv](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing#importing_the_csv_file) file through different ways.
I also did a quick reproduction with a 300MB csv file using the following command and it works fine for me:

`gcloud sql import csv [INSTANCE_NAME] gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[FILE_NAME] \ --database=[DATABASE_NAME] --table=[TABLE_NAME]`